# How to prevent Emacs from moving my mouse pointer out of the way?

Tags: spacemacs, mouse, tooltip

I'm using Spacemacs on MS Windows (msys2 build) and when a tooltip pops up Emacs seems to move my mouse pointer out of the way. How can I prevent this automatic movement?

Answer (score 3):

I do not use Spacemacs, but this could be caused by `mouse-avoidance-mode`. It normally moves the mouse when the cursor is nearby. So it may also apply to tooltips, I am not sure.

You can check if it is enabled with <kbd>C-h v mouse-avoidance-mode</kbd>. If it is not `nil`, you can disable it with `(mouse-avoidance-mode -1)`.

There are also several other options how the mouse is moved, see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mouse-Avoidance.html). I used to set it to `'exile`, which makes the cursor automatically return.

Comment: Sadly it's already nil.

Comment: The low-level function to move the mouse seems to be `set-mouse-position`. You can try to enable the debugger when this function is invoked and see what other function triggered it. To do so evaluate `(debug-on-entry 'set-mouse-position)`. This will only work if whatever moves your mouse, uses this function, but that seems fairly likely. To disable the debugger again use `(cancel-debug-on-entry 'set-mouse-position)`.